# "Multiple definition of" error in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++

I am doing my assignment in C++ using Code Block. My code is following:

main.cpp:

```
#ifndef _common_h_
#include "common.h"
#define _common_h_
#endif

#ifndef _assignment2_cpp_
#include "assignment2.cpp"
#define _assignment2_cpp_
#endif

void writeFile(char* filename, string str)
{
    char* file_name = filename;
    FILE* f = 0;

    f = fopen(file_name, "w");
    if (f == NULL)
        return;

    char    s[2000];

    strcpy(s, str.c_str());

    fwrite(s, strlen(s), 1, f);

    fclose(f);
}

int main()
{
    string  result;

    for(int i = 0; i<MAX_VERTEX; i++)
        strcpy(myGraph.graph[i].vertex.strName, "-1");

    readFile(myGraph, "input.txt");

    switch(myGraph.nOperation)
    {
    case DEPTHFIRSTTRAVERSAL:
        result = depthFirstTraversal(myGraph,myGraph.startVertex);
        writeFile("output.txt", result);
        break;
    case BREADTHFIRSTTRAVERSAL:
        result = breadthFirstTraversal(myGraph,myGraph.startVertex);
        writeFile("output.txt", result);
        break;
    case DEPTHTOPOSORT:
        result = depthTopoSort(myGraph);
        writeFile("output.txt", result);
        break;
    case BREADTHTOPOSORT:
        result = breadthTopoSort(myGraph);
        writeFile("output.txt", result);
        break;
    case MINIMUMSPANTREE:
        result = minSpanTree(myGraph, myGraph.startVertex);
        writeFile("output.txt", result);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

common.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <climits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define     MAX_VERTEX              500

#define     UNDIRECTEDGRAPH         0
#define     DIRECTEDGRAPH           1

#define     DISPLAYGRAPH            0
#define     DEPTHFIRSTTRAVERSAL     1
#define     BREADTHFIRSTTRAVERSAL   2
#define     DEPTHTOPOSORT           3
#define     BREADTHTOPOSORT         4
#define     MINIMUMSPANTREE         5

#define     INCREASINGORDER         0
#define     DECREASINGORDER         1

struct VertexType{
    char        strName[10];
    float       weight;
    bool        isMarked;
    VertexType  *next;
    VertexType()
    {
        strcpy(strName, "");
        weight = 0;
        isMarked = false;
        next = NULL;
    }
};
struct GraphNode{
    VertexType  vertex;
    VertexType  *adjVertex;
    int         indegree;
    int         outdegree;
    bool        isMarked;
    GraphNode(){
        indegree = 0;
        outdegree = 0;
        isMarked = false;
        adjVertex = NULL;
    }
};

struct Graph{
    int         nGraphType;
    int         nOperation;
    int         nVertexNum;
    VertexType  startVertex;
    int         nOrder;

    GraphNode   graph[MAX_VERTEX];
};

Graph   myGraph;
```

assignment2.cpp:

```
#ifndef _common_h_
#include "common.h"
#define _common_h_
#endif

int readFile(Graph &myGraph, char* filename ){
    return 1;
}

string depthFirstTraversal(Graph &myGraph, VertexType startVertex)
{
    string result="";

    return result;
}
string breadthFirstTraversal(Graph &myGraph, VertexType startVertex)
{
    string result="";

    return result;
}
string depthTopoSort(Graph &myGraph)
{
    string result;

    return result;
}
string breadthTopoSort(Graph &myGraph)
{
    string result = "";

    return result;
}
string minSpanTree(Graph &myGraph, VertexType startVertex)
{
    string result="";

    return result;
}
```

And i get the following error when compile it in Code::Blocks:
[image]
Error "multiple difinition of" of all function in assigment2.cpp. But when I compile it with another IDE, it run normal. So what is wrong with my code or Code::Blocks?

Comment: `#include "assignment2.cpp"` is just wrong.

Comment: Your project is probably configured in the proper way, which is to build both `main.cpp` and `assignment2.cpp`, then link the resulting object files to produce an executable. The problem is that by including `assignment2.cpp` in `main.cpp`, you are essentially compiling it twice. Once where it's included as part of another source file, and once where it's compiled as its own translation unit. What you're doing here is an outright anti-pattern. Maybe it works in "another IDE" because you did not correctly configure that IDE to build multiple sources.

Comment: Add your scope/include guards to header files only, and you can use #pragma once instead of #ifdef. `using namespace` is already not recommended but NEVER EVER put a `using namespace std;` in a header file! Watch [stop using `using namespace`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZqjl9HEPZ8) from C++ weekly by Jason Turner

Comment: Please post the output from the "build log" tab as text, not a screenshot of the error list.

Comment: Your issues likely are: 1. Including .cpp files (you shouldn't), 2. `Graph myGraph;` in the header (you should likely move it to `main`; it's possible to have global variables across multiple files too, for that read about `inline` and `extern`).

Answer (score 0):

As compiler message states: you defined functions:

1. `readFile(Graph &myGraph, char* filename )`
2. `depthFirstTraversal(Graph &myGraph, VertexType startVertex)`
3. `breadthFirstTraversal(Graph &myGraph, VertexType startVertex)`

more than once which gives you the error. Usually that is fixed by deleting other definitions of those functions, but your problem is that inside of your `main.cpp` file you are including `assignment2.cpp` file which Codeblocks is automatically linking to your `main.cpp` file afterwards so you end up with multiple definitions of your functions.

You can just simply remove the line in which you are including the `assignment2.cpp` file and the error should go away.

Not releated to your question: I highly suggest you look at [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/include-guards-in-c/) which explains how to use include guards which you are using incorrectly.